# Boundary Points and Metric space

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, elementary-set-theory, metric-spaces, proof-writing

Definition:The boundary of a subset of a metric space X is defined to be the set $\partial{E}$ $=$ $\bar{E} \cap \overline{X\setminus E}$

Definition: A subset E of X is closed if it is equal to its closure, $\bar{E}$.

Theorem: Let C be a subset of a metric space X. C is closed iff $C^c$ is open.

Definition: A subset of a metric space X is open if for each point in the space there exists a ball contained within the space

Show that if $E \cap \partial{E}$ $=$ $\emptyset$ then $E$ is open.

Proof:

$E\cap \partial{E}$ being empty means that $ E\subseteq (\bar{E}^c \cup \overline{X\setminus E}^c)$. Since $E \subseteq \bar{E}$ it follows that $E \subseteq \overline{X\setminus E}^c$ which implies that $E \cap \overline{X\setminus E}$ is empty. Since every subset is a subset of its closure, it follows that $X\setminus E$ $=$ $\overline{X\setminus E}$ and so $X\setminus E$ is closed, and therefore $E$ is open.

Is the proof correct? I would really love feedback.

Comment: Yes it is correct. After saying that $E \cap \overset{-} {(X\setminus E)}$ is empty you can add: $ \overset{-} {(X\setminus E)} \subset X\setminus E$ for clarity.

Comment: You are confusing subspace and subset.

Comment: @WilliamElliot Every subset of a metric space is also a metric space wrt the same metric. May I know where I confused the term? A subspace is a subset, by definition and every subset of a metric space is a subspace (a metric space in its own right).

Comment: The boundary of any subspace is empty.  The boundary of the subset  is what you claimed to be the boundary of the subspace,

Comment: @WilliamElliot What do you mean the boundary of any subspace is empty? Clearly not, (0,1) is a subset\subspace of the reals and 1 is an element of the boundary.

Comment: The boundary of the set (0,1) is {0,1}.   The boundary of the subspace (0,1) is empty because 0 and 1 are not in the subspace (0,1).  Learn something about topological subspaces before replying.

Comment: @William Elliot. Thanks so much for the clarification! I don't see the issue with replying though, I misunderstood a concept and replied merely to further my understanding of the concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After William Elliot's feedback on your proof and [this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3251331/boundary-points-and-metric-space#comment6686712_3251331) of yours, I don't think there is much that needs to be clarified. Still if you have anything specific regarding your proof to ask me, I welcome you to come [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72901/general-chat-with-user-170039).

In any case, let me try to write a proof that I believe is in line with your attempt.

> \begin{align*}E\cap \partial{E}=\emptyset&\implies E\cap(\overline{E}\cap \overline{X\setminus E})=\emptyset\\&\implies (E\cap\overline{E})\cap \overline{X\setminus E}=\emptyset\\&\implies E\cap \overline{X\setminus E}=\emptyset\\&\implies \overline{X\setminus E}\subseteq X\setminus E\\&\implies \overline{X\setminus E}=X\setminus E\end{align*}This shows that $X\setminus E$ is closed and hence $E$ is open.

Answer (score 0):

In any  topological space $X$ and any $E\subset X,$ the 3 sets $int(E),\, int(X\setminus E),\,  \partial E)$ are pair-wise disjoint and their union is $X.$

So if $E\cap \partial E=\emptyset$  then $$E=E\cap X=E\cap (\,int (E) \cup int (X\setminus E)\cup  \partial E\,)=$$ $$=(E\cap int E)\,\cup\, (E\cap int (X\setminus E))\,\cup\, (E\cap \partial E)\subset$$ $$\subset (E\cap int(E)\,\cup \,( E\cap (X\setminus E)\,\cup\, (E\cap \partial E)=$$ $$=int (E)\,\cup \, ( \emptyset)\,\cup \,(\emptyset)=$$ $$=int (E)\subset E$$ so $E=int(E).$

OR, from the first sentence above, for any $E\subset X$ we have $int(E)\subset E\subset \overline E=int(E)\cup \partial E.$

So if $E\cap \partial E=\emptyset$ then $$E=E\cap \overline E=E\cap (int (E) \cup \partial E)=$$ $$=(E\cap int (E))\,\cup \,(E\cap \partial E)=$$  $$=(E\cap int (E))\cup(\emptyset)=$$ $$=int(E)\subset E$$ so $E=int(E).$